# Laravel 4 : Route returning wrong information

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am setting up an API with Laravel so that I can connect with an AngularJS front-end.

I have 2 routes that go to the same controller method -> `BallController@getSpecs`

My routes are set up as follows:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/ball'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'BallController@getIndex');
        Route::get('{id}', 'BallController@getIndex');
        Route::get('specs', 'BallController@getSpecs');
        Route::get('{id}/specs', 'BallController@getSpecs');
    });
});
```

Now  I am having trouble with `Route::get('specs', 'BallController@getSpecs');` route.

The getSpecs method is defined as follows:

```
public function getSpecs($id = null) 
{
    if(empty($id))
    {
        Ball::all()->each(function($ball) {
            $json = [$ball->id => [
                'name'          => $ball->name,
                'core'          => $ball->core->toArray(),
                'coverstock'    => $ball->coverstock->toArray(),
                'finish'        => $ball->finish->toArray(),
                'manufacturer'  => $ball->manufacturer->toArray()
            ]];
        });

        return Response::json($json);
    }
    else
    { 
        $ball = Ball::find($id);

        if(empty($ball))
        {
            return Response::json('You\'ve got no ballss', 404);
        }
        else
        {
            return Response::json([$ball->id => [
                'name'          => $ball->name,
                'core'          => $ball->core->toArray(),
                'coverstock'    => $ball->coverstock->toArray(),
                'finish'        => $ball->finish->toArray(),
                'manufacturer'  => $ball->manufacturer->toArray()
            ]]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `/api/v1/ball/1/specs` specifying an id I get the correct information back, however when I call `/api/v1/ball/specs` my function returns my error message 'You've got no balls'

ID should be null in this cast putting me into the first part of my if statement but for some reason I am getting into my else and getting my error because obviously no ID was provided and the ball won't exist.

Any help/insight will be appreciated.

Edit: I think it may be sending it to the wrong method. I think that `/api/v1/ball/specs` is being sent to `BallController@getIndex` instead of `BallController@getSpecs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the routing:

```
Route::get('{id}', 'BallController@getIndex');
Route::get('specs', 'BallController@getSpecs');
```

When it sees "/api/v1/ball/specs", it will actually call getIndex() with the "id" parameter set to "specs", because that's the first matching route.  One way to fix it would be to define the "specs" route first before you define the "{id}" route.  But a better solution would be to limit the accepted values of the "{id}" parmeter like this...

```
Route::get('{id}', 'BallController@getIndex')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

One other suggestion, there shouldn't be a leading "/" in your prefix values (apparently the code may be working anyway, but they aren't really supposed to be there.  So the complete updated route might look like this...

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ball'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'BallController@getIndex');
        Route::get('specs', 'BallController@getSpecs');
        Route::get('{id}', 'BallController@getIndex')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
        Route::get('{id}/specs', 'BallController@getSpecs')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. Is there any docs or reading you can recommend to better understand why it tries to pass specs as the {id}?

Comment: Well, http://laravel.com/docs/routing.  But basically you just have to realize that the router doesn't know "id" has to be an integer unless you explicitly tell it so. So there isn't any reason the router *wouldn't* think the "specs" part of "/api/v1/ball/specs" is supposed to be the id for your getIndex function.